# Application/Port specific Network shaping tool?

Tags: networking, server

So I've recently made the move to Ubuntu 16.04, from Windows 7, and am looking for a program that can replace the NetLimiter 3 Pro application I used to use to throttle my upload and download speeds for specific applications and their ports.

I have a limited DSL connection speed and one of my applications (Second Life) accesses large amounts of data for object, texture, and map resources and on a large range of IP addresses and needs to be throttled on a specific port to prevent network congestion.

Are there any solutions availible that address these specific needs?

Answer (score 1):

I have used *Trickle* which is a lightweight bandwidth shaper.

It works by setting the upload and download parameters of the application you want to throttle.  I don't know if it can help you with specific port throttling, but I believe by using it with an application, it will work for how you need.

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-get install trickle
```

**Basic Use**

```
trickle -d download-bandwidth -u upload-bandwidth command
```

**Example Use**

```
trickle -d 25 -u 15 firefox
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It does get me closer to my solution, but not quite a bullseye. I need to throttle all of port 80 traffic while leaving the other ports for map coordinates and privilages untouched.